# Application throws OutofMemoryException

Tags: c#, sql, out-of-memory, task, fileinfo

Hello Fellow Programmers,
An application currently running in one of our customers system faces the problem of OutofMemoryException and the application crashes. This problem occurs may be once in one or two weeks. The application developed using c# is used for a manufacturing line. The machine produces 28 different CSV files nearly every 20 seconds. The application is used to find these CSV files and archive the files. Therefore the application queries and carries out update/select on the database table (it is a table with huge amount of data) every second. I have read through the issues and answers from other programmers on this issue and analysed my code accordingly, but due to lack of my experience I could find the memory leak in my code. I would to share here some parts of my code where I believe memory leak can occur. It would be grateful if you share your comments or ideas.

Code

```
public void execute() //This is called every second 
 { 
    if (!this.busyBit) 
    {
        this.busyBit = true;
        CallAsyncFunction();
    }
  }
 protected async virtual void CallAsyncFunction()
 {
     await Task.Factory.StartNew(this.FileOperations); //is this correctly done?
 }
 protected virtual void FileOperations()
 {

   ////Searches for a new csv file
    if (!this. SearchTimestampInsideFileWithOddCounter())
    {
      //return error
    }

    if (!this.ArchiveFile())
    {
      //Archive the file
    }
      this.busyBit = false;
  }
 private bool SearchTimestampInsideFileWithOddCounter()
 {
     var directory = new DirectoryInfo(this.fileSearchPath);
    //Can the below code be a reason? because when I increased 
  //'numberOfFiles' to a huge number, the exception occured more frequently.
     FileInfo[] files = directory.EnumerateFiles().Where(f => 
     f.Extension.Equals(".csv", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
    && f.Attributes != FileAttributes.Archive)                                       
   .OrderByDescending(fi => 
    fi.LastWriteTime).Take(this.numberOfFiles).ToArray();
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
         //Search for the required files from the list
         return true;

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

   }
        return false;
 }
```

Comment: Don't try to *guess* at the source of your memory leak (nothing jumps out in the code you've shown). Use a profiler and *find out*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer may be in

> the application queries and carries out update/select on the database table (it is a table with huge amount of data) every second.

Is the application running all-the-time, or is it running ever n seconds? If it's an always on application, then *if* the database objects are not disposed of properly the memory footprint will grow every cycle.

Comment: Thank you @tymtam ! The application is running all-time. Actually I create an object of the database class as a private member and this class contains members like Connection ID, Connection string,ExecuteReader(),etc. So by database objects do you mean them?